# regarding usage of hashing

Tags: encryption, symmetric, commitments, decryption

I have a question regarding pitfalls of using only encryption.

Suppose Bob and Alice want to flip a coin over a network. Alice proposes the following protocol.

1. Alice randomly selects a value X ∈ {0,1}.
2. Alice generates a 256-bit random symmetric key K.
3. Using the AES cipher, Alice computes Y = E(X,R,K), where R consists of 255 randomly selected bits.
4. Alice sends Y to Bob.
5. Bob guesses a value Z ∈ {0,1} and tells Alice.
6. Alice gives the key K to Bob who computes (X,R) = D(Y, K).
7. If X = Z then Bob wins, otherwise Alice wins.

This protocol is insecure.

- a. Explain how Alice can cheat.
- b. Using a cryptographic hash function h, modify this protocol so that Alice can't cheat.

My guess is that Alice can repudiate the fact that she did not receive the value Z sent by Bob and hence does not provide the key. Can anyone suggest other ways in which Alice can cheat ?

Comment: _"Alice can repudiate the fact that she did not receive the value Z"_ has one too much negation. We could say _"Alice can repudiate the fact that she received Z, or that value of Z"_. But that's not the expected answer. Alice has another way to cheat that could convince you (before you find her technique) that she indeed won, even if she never invokes a transmission error. Recommendation: imagine you are Alice, and want to cheat. Note: "X∥R" (or "X,R" and "(X, R)" as there was [before my edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/84177/1)) means bit X concatenated with R.

Comment: my bad on the part X||R its actually (X,R) since K is used to decrypt the ciphertext

Comment: If the exercise is given as it stands [after your new edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/84177/6) then it is uses a non-strandard notation, and is borderline wrong. At step 3 we are left to insert parenthesis as appropriate in "E(X,R,K)"; and, independently, wonder if we should read "127" where there is "255", or choose a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for AES, which Alice and Bob must agree on. New recommendation: first decide and understand what Alice is supposed to do, then apply the previous recommendation.

Comment: Hint: (assuming $E$ is AES-GCM); given two keys $K_1, K_2$, it is possible to find a 256 bit message that would successfully decrypt (to two different random messages) with those two keys (assuming a fixed well-known nonce and fixed or no AAD).

Comment: @poncho: you are adding an interesting twist with authenticated encryption not being usable as commitment. But the question has _using only encryption_. And it's hard enough to make sense out of the [original copy/paste](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/84177/1) and find what the question should have been.

Comment: @fgrieu: if it's unauthenticated encryption, then it's even easier...

Comment: @poncho: Yes I think that the actual question is with unauthenticated encryption, and poor notation, possibly using the raw AES block cipher and 255 where 127 is meant; and the OP is having a hard time figuring out the question in part because of these issues.